# Flutter Firebase not returning correct queried documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Screenshot of my database]I want to find all the documents in the 'communities' collection, where the user's id is contained in the 'members' array.
But my firebase query is just returning ALL the documents in the 'communities' collection instead of just the ones I queried.

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get userCommunities {
    return communityCollection.where('members', arrayContains: uid).orderBy('lastActive', descending: true).snapshots();
  }

...

StreamBuilder(
            stream: DBService().userCommunities,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData)
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name']));
                });
              else
                return Container();
            },
          ),
```

testCommunity2 does not contain the user's id in members but my app displays both communities in the listview

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I found that my uid was returning null in `return communityCollection.where('members', arrayContains: uid)`